# how to prevent link padding during hover from extending paragraph padding

Tags: html, css

I am trying to list some links (with no bullets or numbers) and I have an a:hover class that adds some padding and background color. The code looks something like this

```
<p>
<a href="google.ca">Google</a></br>
<a href="bing.ca">Garbage Google</a>
</p>
```

And the css looks like this

```
.p{
padding: 20px;
background-color: #ffffff;
display: inline-block;
}

a:hover{
padding: 0px 5px 0px 5px;
background-color: #ff0000;
}
```

I saw that `display: inline-block;` would make sure the padding on the paragraph wouldn't extend across the page (which I didn't want) but I don't fully understand how it works. Whenever I hover over the largest item in the list ("Garbage Google" in this case) the padding on the paragraph extends to accommodate the new padding on the list item even though there is plenty of room for it to go. Any suggestions?

Comment: What do you mean by extending `p` padding? The padding on the paragraph is constant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Block level elements (like `p`) are, by default, 100% the width of their parent element, so they tend to act like springs (always wanting to be expanded as much as possible).

Inline elements (like `a`) are, by default, only as wide as their content, so they act like rubber bands (always wanting to shrink down to the smallest possible size without crushing their content).

When your `a:hover` class becomes active, you are increasing the size of the inline `a` element and that causes its size to increase, which in turn is causing the `p`, which contains the a to increase as well.

What you can do is set a width for your `p` element that is larger than the largest width any of your `a` elements will be when they are hovered over. Since you've set your `p` to be `inline-block`, its width is acting like `inline` (rubber band), but you need to have that rubber band be held open at a point that is larger than the content will ever be so it won't be affected by the content growing and shrinking.

Doing this will cause the size of the `p` to remain constant as the `a` elements inside grow and shrink due to hovering.